# Including external JSP file to JSP in WebContent

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to load external file (not in WebContent folder) and then somehow include it to JSP file which is in WebContent folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSP can only include static/dynamic content using URL's:

- Relative to the current JSP
- Absoulte from the context root of the application